# Increment many rows of an auto-increment identity field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm in a situation where I need to increment the id of a table where the id is greater than or equal to 4507081. Lets say the increment needs to be 17623.

So basically the sql I want to run is

```
UPDATE baseData b
SET b.id = b.id + 17623
WHERE b.id >= 4507081
```

However I get:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4524704' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I guess it doesnt realise that that primary key will have it's id increased too. How do I need to do this increment?

Additionally I then need to do the same on a table that also uses this id (and is a foreign key)

```
Update baseDataPerson p
SET p.baseDataID = p.baseDataID + 17623
WHERE p.baseDataID >= 4507081
```

So this may cause further issue with the first update, but it does have on update cascade on it so maybe that means the id updates in the first query will carry through?

---

Extra info on why this needs to happen - basically this table is a on a separate server in a shadow db where we do alot of processing to detect data updates and then later do a single update to the live db to stop the live server getting overwhelmed. One of the web dev's did something that caused a 17623 gap in the id's on the live server (this table should never change on the live server apart from the updates coming from the shadow db) and so messed up the system. There are now customer records referencing id's after the gap on the live server so i have to put the gap into the shadow table to align the id's again.

Comment: You just want to reset the auto increment ID to a new starting point? Use `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: When increment the PRIMARY KEY field of the table, some PRIMARY KEYS are duplicated. It means that you are trying to add PRIMARY KEYS which are already exist in the table. That is why you get that type pf error message. Check PRIMARY KEYS are duplicated or not

Comment: No, I am trying to recreate a gap in the ID's - lets say you had a table with rows with id's 1 to 1000 already in it, how would you change records 301 to 1000 so that they are 801 to 1500 i.e. you end up with records 1 to 300 and 801 to 1500? With the additional issue of the id of this table being reference as a foreign key in another many to many table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `ORDER BY` clause in your `UPDATE`, to prevent duplicates:

```
UPDATE baseData b
SET b.id = b.id + 17623
WHERE b.id >= 4507081
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

Doing it in this order ensures that the old value will be moved out of the way before a new value is put in its place. And the `ON UPDATE CASCADE`s will update all the foreign keys properly.

Comment: Its the second thing yes - if I do it this way what will happen with the many to many table with foreign key to this tables id? It has on update/delete cascade (obviously ill update that table too, but worried what will happen with the first update)

Comment: perhaps I could disable foreign key checks, do the update on the many many table first - and then do the above?

Comment: I just posted a new answer that I think should solve the problem cimpletely.